# storing dynamic data on phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I am building phonegapp application,

In my app there will be database of phrases..
I want the application to work offline so - I need to save those phrases locally, read, and update.

How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

A quick (and dirty) solution would be to use HTML 5 local storage.

However if you are looking for something more refined the cordova community has already created plugins which can access popular mobile databases. For example [this](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) is a pretty good plugin.